# How to extract all the child nodes in XML and save in Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to Extract all the child nodes from XML and need to save all the nodes in excel sheet in one Column.I am specifying the XML inside the Excel sheet.Given below the Xml.Can any one please help how to extract.

XML:

```
<Company>
    <EmpName>Kathir</EmpName>
    <EmpAge>12</EmpAge>
    <EmpPlace>23</EmpPlace>
    <Salary>
        <Income>1234</Income>
        <Pf>233</Pf>
    </Salary>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to Microsoft XML, V6.0 before running this code.

```
Sub xml()

    Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XDoc.Load ("C:\test.xml")
    Set xEmpDetails = XDoc.DocumentElement
    Set xEmployee = xEmpDetails.FirstChild
    For Each xEmployee In xEmpDetails.ChildNodes
        For Each xChild In xEmployee.ChildNodes
            MsgBox xChild.BaseName & " " & xChild.Text
        Next xChild
    Next xEmployee
End Sub
```